# How do I programmatically bind a WPF Datagrid to a ObservableCollection of custom objects?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I've been searching for ages and haven't found any solution. Title basically covers what I'm trying to accomplish. Here's what I have so far that clearly isn't working with irrelevant stuff cut out.

In MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ModGrid = new DataGrid();
    ModGrid.CanUserReorderColumns = false;

    DataGridTextColumn Name = new DataGridTextColumn();
    Name.Header = "Name";
    Name.MinWidth = 45;
    Name.Width = (DataGridLength)(new DataGridLengthConverter()).ConvertFromString("*");
    Binding nameBinding = new Binding("Name");
    nameBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    Name.Binding = nameBinding;
    ModGrid.Columns.Add(Name);

    DataGridTextColumn Tags = new DataGridTextColumn();
    Tags.Header = "Tags";
    Tags.MinWidth = 40;
    Tags.Width = 200;
    Binding tagsBinding = new Binding("Tags");
    tagsBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    Tags.Binding = tagsBinding;
    ModGrid.Columns.Add(Tags);

    // There are more columns but you get the idea

    ModGrid.ItemsSource = Database.Mods;
}

private void RibbonWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ModGrid.DataContext = Database.Mods;
}
```

Later I add items to Database.Mods

```
void Fetcher_RequestComplete(bool error, string result, int requestsLeft)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        Database.Mods = Parser.ParseMods(result);
    }
}
```

This is all that's in database.cs

```
public static class Database
{
    public static ObservableCollection<Mod> Mods = new ObservableCollection<Mod>();
}
```

And this is all that's in mod.cs

```
public class Mod
{
    public Mod() { }

    public Image Status;
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
    public string Author;
    public string Tags;
    public int Views;
    public string Link;
    public string[] Versions;
    public string[] TagsList;
}
```

Sorry about the code spam but I haven't seen how to do this entirely programmatically and it's necessary that I do. Any responses at all are *very* appreciated!

**Edit:**

While I did find an answer, if your in this situation I've found it would be much better to just make a custom control and have access from the XAML that way.

Comment: I have to ask - why does it have to be in code behind?  This creates "nasty" code and really makes it difficult to maintain.  What is preventing you from using a view model with the data bindings set up in XAML and using a Data Template to set it up correctly? I mean using this approach - you might as well go back to winforms....

Comment: I'm using ribbon tabs and I have a contentcontrol so when you switch between tabs the content changes. I create the stuff to put in the contentcontrol in the code and assign it to the contentcontrol manually. This probably isn't the best way of doing it but I'm not nearly experienced enough with XAML to do it any other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: your question is a little bit wrong because you do not **BIND** something to your grid you simply **SET** the itemssource

nevertheless there are 2 ways you can achieve what you want.

```
void Fetcher_RequestComplete(bool error, string result, int requestsLeft)
{
 if (!error)
 {
    Database.Mods.AddRange(Parser.ParseMods(result));//you can use foreach or write AddRange extension
 }
}
```

or

```
void Fetcher_RequestComplete(bool error, string result, int requestsLeft)
{
 if (!error)
 {
    ModGrid.ItemsSource = Parser.ParseMods(result));
 }
}
```

the cleaner way would be MVVM but thats was not your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Your Mod class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to update the screen appropriately.

[How To: Implement Property Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

Comment: Just tried doing that but no luck. This is my implementation [here](http://pastebin.com/BgQCTxUZ)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
```

Comment: If you debug does NotifyProtertyChanged get called?  Setting both ItemsSource and DataContext is maybe too much.  Try dropping the DataContext.  Why the satic database where you create a fresh (new) database on each call.   How do you expect the update to be seen if you are delivering a new on the property?   Why a static?

Comment: NotifyPropertyChanged doesn't get called when assigning it here `Database.Mods = Parser.ParseMods(result);` Dropping DataContext didn't solve the problem. I'm not sure when you mean about the database. I didn't know `= new ObservableCollection<Mod>()` was done on each call if that's what you mean. But dropping that part didn't change anything either.